# Django build_absolute_uri throwing NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Have tried numerous related solutions previously posted here to no effect. I'm obviously missing something. I am using Django 1.4. I have a process that generates a random number of jpeg files. I am trying to create a combination of views/template/templatetags that will let me dynamically display the images. No models are involved. Used the idea of a templatetag filter from [Lois Di Qual](http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/django-absolute-media-uris-from-templates/)

The settings.py file has the proper TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS installed. Thanks in advance.

This is what I have:

Template:

```
{% load mytemplatetags %}
{% for fn in jpg_names %}
    {{ fn|absolute_img_uri:request }}  
{% endfor %}
```

Template Tags

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

register = template.Library()

'''
Usage: {{ fn|absolute_media_url:request }}
'''
@register.filter
def absolute_img_uri(fn, request):
    return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("returnImage", kwargs={'fn':fn}))
```

View:

```
def returnImage(request,**kwargs):
path = "/opt/local/var/media/facstool/"
fn = kwargs['fn']
img = open(str(path)+fn,'rb').read()
response = HttpResponse(img,mimetype='image/jpeg')
return response
```

Urls:

```
import ri.tools.views as rv
urlpatterns = patterns('ri.tools.views',
url(r'^$', 'index', name="index"),
url(r'defineParameters','defineParameters',name='defineParameters'),
url(r'downloadcsv','downloadcsv',name='downloadcsv'),
url(r'downloadpdf','downloadpdf',name='downloadpdf'),
url(r'downloadZipFile','downloadZipFile',name='downloadZipFile'),
url(r'returnImage/(?P<fn>.*)',rv.returnImage,name='returnImage'),
)
```

*-*Edit*-*

Traceback:

```
NoReverseMatch at /tools/defineParameters
Reverse for 'returnImage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'fn': u'Lep-_Clone12_Median__ss_293F_Median__ss_293F_H8_graph.jpg'}' not found.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/tools/defineParameters
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'returnImage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'fn': u'Lep-_Clone12_Median__ss_293F_Median__ss_293F_H8_graph.jpg'}' not found.
Exception Location:  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 396
Python Executable:  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did not find to solution to why it doesn't work, but I did find a solution that does work. Hopefully this can help others or it may give a clue to someone why the original method failed.

I made the following changes:

Template:

```
{% for fn in jpg_names %}
  <img src="/tools/returnImage/{{ fn }}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('ri.tools.views',
url(r'^$', 'index', name="index"),
url(r'defineParameters','defineParameters',name='defineParameters'),
url(r'downloadcsv','downloadcsv',name='downloadcsv'),
url(r'downloadpdf','downloadpdf',name='downloadpdf'),
url(r'downloadZipFile','downloadZipFile',name='downloadZipFile'),
url(r'returnImage/.*','returnImage',name='returnImage'),)
```

Views:

```
def returnImage(request):
   path = "/opt/local/var/media/facstool/"
   _, fn = os.path.split(request.META['PATH_INFO'])
   f = open(str(path)+fn,'rb')
   img = f.read()
   f.close()
   os.remove(str(path)+fn)
   response = HttpResponse(img,mimetype='image/jpeg')
   return response
```

Basically this adds the filename to the img tag, then strips off the filename in the view, opens it on the server, reads it into a variable, deletes the original file and returns the image. It is the behavior I wanted, I just don't understand why the OP wouldn't have worked.